# How to make a equalizer for HLS streaming videos?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, http-live-streaming, equalizer

I want to add an EQ to HLS streaming videos.

So far:

1. AVAudioEngine seems only support local file;
2. Download .ts and merge into .mp3 to make it local can not guarantee real time effect;
3. MTAudioProcessingTap needs the audio track. For remote .mp3 I can extract the audio track but not for HLS.

Any suggestion?